# How can I find why 'rpc.gssd' starts every time?

Tags: systemd, services

I have SLES 12 and I saw that every time I reboot my computer, the process `rpc.gssd` (which is Kerberos) starts by itself. I've tried to disable it using `systemctl` but there's no such a service. All I can see is a PID.

```
pgrep rpc.gssd
```

How can I dig and find which service triggers that one? Or how can I disable it permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
systemctl status PID
```

You should see something like this:

```
$ systemctl status 16736
● salt-master.service - The Salt Master Server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/salt-master.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-09-10 05:11:21 MSK; 1min 8s ago
  Main PID: 16736 (salt-master)
  CGroup: /system.slice/salt-master.service
       ├─16736 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/salt-master
       ├─16744 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/salt-master
       ├─16751 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/salt-master
```

[systemctl(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#status%20PATTERN...%7CPID...%5D) says:

> status [PATTERN...|PID...]]
>
> Show terse runtime status information about one or more units, followed by most recent log data from the journal. If a PID is passed, show information about the unit the process belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, on SLES 12 and higher (and possibly various Linux distros) rpc.gssd is controlled by systemd through "rpc-gssd.service".  That service is considered "static" (always starts during boot) rather than configurable as "enabled" or "disabled".  (You can verify this with "systemctl status rpc-gssd".)  Since it cannot be "disabled", if you want to prevent it from starting during boot, you must "mask" it, for example:

systemctl mask rpc-gssd.service

And there is also an "unmask" directive to bring such things back.

FYI, it is incorrect to say that rpc.gssd is Kerberos.  It is an interface through which NFS can make use of Kerberos.  Technically is it implemented at the rpc layer, so I believe that other RPC services could be coded to take advantage of it as well.  However, I don't know of any RPC-based service (other than NFS) which does so.  The nfs-utils source package supplies rpc.gssd.